# How to make native node mongo return an err in callback

Tags: node.js, node-mongodb-native

I need to test error handling in a node app I'm working on. How can I make Mongo return an error in its callback so I can test error handling in my app?

```
collection.findOne({a: b}, function(err, item) {
   // how can I build a query to make an err?
});
```

Comment: Maybe close mongo server?

Comment: @Daiwei Yea, that works. I was hoping there was a way I could pass in a bad query to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way I'm thinking is to use an invalid opereator:

```
collection.findOne({foo: {'$fooooo': true}}, function(err, item) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

prints:

```
{ [MongoError: invalid operator: $fooooo] name: 'MongoError' }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your test, rather than `require`ing your actual Mongo driver, you could use a mock dummy driver that returns errors.

Answer (score -1):

Running thisIsNotACollection.findOne({a:b}) in the CLI gives -  ReferenceError: thisIsNotACollection is not defined. As long as you never define thisIsNotACollection as a collection you should consistently get an error back.

Comment: This is conceptually wrong, the CLI throws an error because you are using it wrong. You should use `db.thisIsNotACollection.findOne` and it will not fail because mongodb is schemaless and you don't need to define collections upfront. On the other hand OP was asking about mongodb's node driver